# Find the generating function for $ a_n = n^4$ .

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Find the generating function for $a_n = n^4$.

How should I approach this question? I have tried to go $1,16,81\dots$ and generate the function with the series but no idea how to do so.

Comment: $\frac{1}{(1-x)}= \sum_{k \ge 0} x^k$<br>
$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}= \sum_{k \ge 0} (k+1)x^k$<br>
$\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}= \sum_{k \ge 0} (k+2)(k+1)x^k$<br>
$\frac{6}{(1-x)^4}= \sum_{k \ge 0} (k+2)(k+1)(k+3)x^k$<br>
$\frac{24}{(1-x)^5}= \sum_{k \ge 0} (k+3)(k+4)(k+2)(k+1)x^k$

Comment: Do these equations give you some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Notice

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$

Take a derivative to get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) x^{n} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$

Now we get

$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^n.$$

Keep going like this.

Comment: is there a way not taking derivative?

Comment: You could divine it from the gods ;-).

There probably is but I'm not smart enough to know it off the top of my head.

Comment: What derivative? You just repeatedly multiply your series $x+2^4x^x+3^4x^3+...$ by $1-x$, until things start to make sense. Admittedly, derivatives make it a lot easier, but...

Comment: do you mind showing me all the steps (or internet page) so I can learn... I can't find solution of this question on the internet. I have stuck on this question for a few hours already. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} n^4 z^n
&=\sum_{n \ge 0} \left(\binom{n}{1}+14\binom{n}{2}+36\binom{n}{3}+24\binom{n}{4}\right) z^n \\
&=\sum_{n \ge 1} \binom{n}{1} z^n + 14\sum_{n \ge 2}\binom{n}{2} z^n + 36\sum_{n \ge 3}\binom{n}{3} z^n + 24\sum_{n \ge 4}\binom{n}{4} z^n \\
&=z \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n+1}{1} z^n + 14z^2\sum_{n \ge 0}\binom{n+2}{2} z^n + 36z^3\sum_{n \ge 0}\binom{n+3}{3} z^n + 24z^4\sum_{n \ge 0}\binom{n+4}{4} z^n \\
&=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2} + \frac{14z^2}{(1-z)^3} + \frac{36z^3}{(1-z)^4} + \frac{24z^4}{(1-z)^5} \\
&= \frac{z + 11 z^2 + 11 z^3 + z^4}{(1-z)^5}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the answer is to insert the terms 1,16,81,256 into the OEIS query form and read the generating function there: https://oeis.org/A000583 .